# Get owner form from checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an easy way in jQuery to return the owner form for a deeply-nested checkbox (or input) element? Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```

Then I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('checkbox.checkall').each(function() { 
    // Access form element of the checkbox here
});
```

In the above example, I would like to obtain the form to which the checkbox belongs. Natually, I could do this using a chained `parent()` method, but the checkbox might not always be the same nesting depth from the root form element.

Sorry if it's not clear, but it's difficult to explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) form

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").closest("form");
```

From jQuery API:

> **Description**: Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.
>
> .closest( selector )
>
> selector: A string containing a selector
> expression to match elements against.

Comment: How might I then go about accessing the other checkbox elements in the form? Using `$('input:checkbox').closest('form').children();` returns the table element. However, I'd like to access all `checkbox` elements that exist in the root form...

Comment: `$(this.form).find('input:checkbox')` where `this` is the current checkbox (we are inside the checkbox click handler).

Answer (score 2):

Form fields have a `form` property which returns the FORM element that contains them.

```
$('checkbox.checkall').each(function() { 
    // Access form element of the checkbox here
    var form = this.form;
});
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63239895

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/9FPrX/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could also use parents() thus:

```
$("input:checkbox").parents("form");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) sounds like the function you need.

It will return the closest parent of the element you gave to the function.

Answer (score 0):

use `parent()`

```
$("input:checkbox").parent("form");
```

parents will give you all relevant parent(form) of this checkbox